# Restrict Capability of Administrator to Create, Edit and Delete Pages in Multisite

Tags: multisite, user-roles, capabilities

In my multisite installation, I need to restrict administrators from being able to create, edit, and delete pages. That is, I need all pages to be created/edited/deleted by superadmins while administrators continue to have all other default administrator capabilities except those three.

The plugin User Role Scoper is not working for me and while I have seen [this Q&A about removing an administrator capability](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77349/remove-ability-for-administrators-to-delete-administrators), I am too new to coding to know how to modify this advice for this situation.

Any guidance about how to proceed here would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use Advanced Access Manager plugin to manage rights and permissions with users and roles.

First, don't change administrator capabilities or you also lose those.

Instead, select the User you want to change the permissions for and adjust that person's Admin settings.

Comment: Hi Lee, welcome to WP.SE. Normally plugin recommendations are not that well received. If the plugin is gone or updates to a point where it does not work like that anymore, the answer quickly becomes useless. Please try to show a bit of code and explain in a bit more detail why things should in your opinion be done in this or that way. There's a "help" link when [edit]ing an answer as well as the [faq] that will guide you there. Thanks and have a nice time.